# how to wait for the completion of Future without 'async'

Tags: dart

how to wait for the completion of Future without 'async' and 'futures'?

In the library that I use all functions are asynchronous.

```
// must return <bool>
bool my_func(int x){

          //returns Future<int>
  var tmp = somelib.somefunc( ... );
  //wait y
  return x == y;
}
```

I tried to write my 'await', but
waiting for a result with a while loop freezes everything.

```
dynamic my_await(Future f) {
  dynamic x;
  bool completed = false;
  f.then((v){
    x = v;
    completed = true;
  });
  do {} while (!completed);
  return x;
}
```

`Dart VM version: 1.24.3 (Mon Dec 18 16:57:48 2017) on "linux_x64"`

Comment: There is no way. It would be better to explain what you try to accomplisg with the while loop. And what is "everything"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A synchronous function, or really, any Dart function, returns a value immediately when you call them. If you want to return a boolean immediately, and the value of that boolean depends on the result that some future completes with, then there is *no way* to compute that boolean in time.

If you need to wait for a future, then your function *is* asynchronous. You need to return something immediately, even if you don't know the result yet. That's what a `Future` is. It's not magical in any way, it's just an object that you can set a callback on which gets called when some result is ready.

So, you need to return a `Future<bool>` for this to work.

Dart is single-threaded. Without using isolates, there is no concurrency. Instead asynchronous functions work by taking turns, giving time for other code to run, e.g., while they wait on a future. If you just do a `do {} while (!completed);` then no other code gets to run, which means that nothing will be able to set `completed` to true.

Comment: _"Dart is single-threaded. Without using isolates, there is no concurrency."_  -  If I use isolates, could I then wait synchronously, i. e. block an isolate until my condition is met? If that is possible, that would enable waiting for a Future without the need for async and the need to return a "Future" value.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to dart, so not sure if this is the correct way of doing it, but I've solved this issue by using the function `whenCompleted()` on the `Future` returned by the async method I'm calling.

Here `openDatabase` returns a `Future`.

```
abstract class IBaseDatabaseHandler {
  Database sqliteDbHandler;

  IBaseDatabaseHandler.sqlite(String dataBasePath) {
    sqfliteFfiInit();

    var databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
    databaseFactory
        .openDatabase(dataBasePath)
        .whenComplete(() => sqliteDbHandler);
  }
}
```